# GNU linker ld - linking against a library at a specific location

Tags: gcc, linker

Let's say I have these 2 libraries with the *same* name, `/usr/local/lib/libxxx.so` and `/opt/lib/libxxx.so`. Both `/usr/local/lib/` and `/opt/lib` *have to be* on the search path (for the linker to find other required libraries). What should be specified to the linker (`ld`, *not* `ld.so`) so that it will find the correct one which is under `/opt/lib/`?

Added 2018-01-23 21:17 (UTC+8)

Yes, that's my understanding too, though I don't fully grasp what "All -L options apply to all -l options, regardless of the order in which the options appear" means.

Here's the details. The link options created by the `configure` script (sorry it's a bit hard to read) is

`-lz -Wl,-rpath,/opt/moose/tbb44_20150728/lib -L/opt/moose/tbb44_20150728/lib -ltbb -ltbbmalloc -L/opt/moose/petsc-3.7.6/mpich-3.2_gcc-7.2.0-opt/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/moose/petsc-3.7.6/mpich-3.2_gcc-7.2.0-opt/lib -L/opt/moose/mpich-3.2/gcc-7.2.0/lib -L/opt/moose/gcc-7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0 -L/opt/moose/gcc-7.2.0/lib64 -L/opt/moose/gcc-7.2.0/lib -lpetsc -lsuperlu_dist -lcmumps -ldmumps -lsmumps -lzmumps -lmumps_common -lpord -lparmetis -lmetis -lHYPRE -lscalapack -lflapack -lfblas -lX11 -lmpifort -lgfortran -lquadmath -lmpicxx -lstdc++ -lm -Wl,-rpath,/opt/moose/gcc-7.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/moose/gcc-7.2.0/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/moose/gcc-7.2.0/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/moose/mpich-3.2/gcc-7.2.0/lib -lmpi -lgomp -lgcc_s -lpthread -ldl -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

and here's the error message when the linker tries to find `libmetis.so` when linking a test binary

`/usr/bin/ld: gk_cur_jbufs: TLS definition in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmetis.so.5 section .tdata mismatches non-TLS definition in /opt/moose/petsc-3.7.6/mpich-3.2_gcc-7.2.0-opt/lib/libmetis.so section .data
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmetis.so.5: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1368: recipe for target 'unit_tests-dbg' failed`

Based on the search order, I don't understand why it tried to look for it in  both search paths `/opt/moose/petsc-3.7.6/mpich-3.2_gcc-7.2.0-opt/lib` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-L /opt/lib -L /usr/local/lib` , in that order, so /opt/lib is searched first.

The docs says:

> **-L searchdir**
>   Add path searchdir to the list of paths that ld will search for
>   archive libraries and ld control scripts.  You may use this option any
>   number of times.  The directories are searched in the order in
>              which they are specified on the command line.  Directories specified on the command line are searched before the default
>   directories.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide some more details. Thanks for your help!